# Writing OS Bootable Files without Formatting or Deleting the Files on it to USB FLASH DRIVE

Tags: usb-flash-drive, operating-systems, formatting, bootable-media

i just want to know if there is a way i can write an installation OS files to USB Flash Drive **without** formatting the files on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GParted to shrink the current partition of the USB drive, and create a new partition for the OS files. As always, before you do anything, back up your USB drive. Also ensure that there's enough space on the drive to keep the extracted OS files as well as the existing files on the USB drive.

To do the resize and create a new partition without deleting the data currently on the USB drive, you can follow the steps in this guide: https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted

Essentially the steps are (slightly modified from https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions):

(Step 0:) Back up anything really valuable. This is a pretty tried and tested formula but things can go wrong. A power cut at the wrong moment could really ruin your day if you haven't backed up.

1. Boot to a LiveCD or LiveUSB drive in "try me" mode.
2. Load gparted (should be installed by default, you can apt-get it if it's not)
3. Resize your partitions (right click, click resize, follow the instructions).
4. Click apply and sit back while it does the job.
5. Create the new partition on the unallocated space you just freed up.
6. Reboot, taking out the USB stick or CD when it tells you to.